# Makefile to compile and execute c program

Tags: c, makefile

I have created a c program `test.c,` which compiles and runs properly and have created the executable `testexec` from that file which also runs. I am trying to create a make file which will first compile `test.c` and then run `testexec` after compiling. This make file doesn't produce any errors, but it only runs testexec, without first compiling test.c:

```
all: test.c
        gcc test.c
        ./testexec
```

Comment: Your compilation creates a program `a.out`; you can't execute `./testexec` unless something else created it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I previously ran a command that created `./testexec`. I tried `gcc test.c testexec` so the executable created would be called testexec instead of a.out but it's still not working

Comment: You use `-o testexec` to create a program named `testexec`. That is pretty basic manual bashing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually I got it! I added `-o`, so the line was now `gcc test.c -o testexec`. I thought -o meant the makefile will NOT re-compile it (according to the manual). Do you know why that made it work?

Comment: Why not `gcc -o testexec test.c`? Then `./testexec` makes sense.

Comment: `-o` is for naming the resulting executable (or generically the *output* of your command)

Answer (score -1):

A generic `makefile` looks like below for any code.

```
INCL   = add here if any header file is there
SRC    = test.c
OBJ    = $(SRC:.c=.o)
EXE    = testexec

CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -c
RM      = rm -rf

all: testexec
testexec: test.o
        gcc -o testexec test.o  
test.o: test.c
        gcc -c test.c 
clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ) $(EXE)
```

Comment: You need to use `${OBJ}` (or `$(OBJ)`) and `${SRC}` a bit more systematically.